# Add thick borders to the corner edges of a view in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

How can I add a thick lines across the corners of a view in android studio, something similar to what looks a photo frame. Something like the image given below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it would be significantly easier if you would just use a `vector graphic` as a `backgound` for this view, which then contains your content.
Then you would get the same effect but with a way lower programming effort.

**EDIT:**

If you want to get this effect using `VectorGraphics` you can just create that Gaphic with one of the free Vector Graphic tools like Inkscape, Gimp, or if you prefer an Online Version [vectr.com](https://vectr.com). If you created this you can basically just copy it to your project folder and create a resource from it.

You can do this by right-clicking your `drawable` folder in `AndroidStudio` and choosing New>ImageResource. AndroidStudio should guide you through the process.

If you have done that, you go to the LayoutFile and switch to XML. Then you can just navigate to your view and add the line:

```
android:background="@drawable/yourNamehere"
```

This will make your Vector file, the `BackgroudResource` of the View.

Comment: Any references or code examples can you provide please?

Comment: Edit done. Hope the new Answer help to clarify how to do that.

Comment: ok thanks much appreciated! Does this work well if i need a transparent background and also want to resize the UI? Asking as to make sure this does not create problems with these two requirements. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom view and draw thick lines on all corners like shown in the image.

You can then set the view as parent view of your imageview or any view & it will draw the frame around your view.

You can find more about drawing custom views here:

https://blog.mindorks.com/create-your-own-custom-view

You can draw lines (in this case, it's the only option), circles, rectangles & anything you want with custom views. Just give it a try & it will be fun. ;)

Comment: As suggested by @TIMBLOCKER is the vector graphic an easy approach?

Comment: Yes, It is. But if you can't make one then you can go with my solution. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated!